# HDMI ports stopped working on 14.04 updates

Tags: 14.04, hdmi, monitor

Situation is that my zotac box only has an hdmi port for the monitor, so this problem is hard to trouble shoot. If I load the original 14.04 LTS on the zotac box I full monitor capabilities through HDMI. However, if I apply the current ubuntu upgrades as of Dec 12th, I immediately loose my HDMI monitor.

The box has a GPU Radeon HD 6320, if that helps.

Any ideas how I can proceed to apply the appropriate upgrades without loosing my monitor?

Is there a way, to step through the updates in Ubuntu, in order to find which one is causing the problem? This all or nothing approach is difficult to trouble shoot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what kind of graphics you're using...

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue with a Lenovo ideacentre when using HDMI for video output.

I've re-installed and 14.04 base install runs fine, applying updates kills X. I can still ssh in but not kill the Xorg process.

Upgrading to 14.10 had the same problem.

I've resorted to re-installing 14.04 and not applying updates.

I suspect that the issue is related to xorg driver updates or kernel configuration.

Comment: Sounds like this problem is more pervasive and is under reported in this version.

Comment: I believe that it is related to this bug:

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11107

Running the script I've managed to get my monitor to be recognised with the latest upgrades.

Comment: Mike any instructions on how to apply this script. There seems to be at least two scripts in bug thread and I'm not sure how I should apply these scripts.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
#Fix TV state when HDMI link is lost.
#By Mario Limonciello <email address hidden>

OUTPUT="HDMI-0"
BAD_MODE="1280x720"
GOOD_MODE="1920x1080"

for MODE in $BAD_MODE $GOOD_MODE; do
 DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output $OUTPUT --mode $MODE
 sleep 2
done

Comment: Apologies, I should have included full instructions.

vi fix-hdmi.sh

#!/bin/sh
#Fix TV state when HDMI link is lost.
#By Mario Limonciello <email address hidden>

OUTPUT="HDMI-0"
BAD_MODE="1280x720"
GOOD_MODE="1920x1080"

for MODE in $BAD_MODE $GOOD_MODE; do
 DISPLAY=:0 xrandr --output $OUTPUT --mode $MODE
 sleep 2
done


once the file was created:

chmod +x fix-hdmi.sh

./fix-hdmi.sh

This restarted my HDMI output. I then disabled the xfsettingsd in the application autostart menu in Session and startup settings. This seems to have stopped my issues completely.

Comment: This script isn't working for me. Still left with a monitor with no signal.